# Tomcat 6.0 is getting stopped after certain time automatically

Tags: tomcat6

Tomcat 6.0 is getting stoped after certain time automatically.. My machine is never turned off. but still this process is stopped . I am using My tomcat server in production mode.. and I really don't feel good starting my server daily.

What could be the reason because in Production mode server should never get stopped.

Comment: No exceptions or even errors in logs?

Comment: Paste the logs here. THere will be somethng useful there

Answer (score 0):

Check in your task scheduler;
Go To start->type in search task schduler

go to task scheduler. Check whether any task is running to stop the serverr.

or you can increase permgen space.
Server might be stop because of out of memory exception.